# Unix: only show links different than 2

Tags: unix, hyperlink

I need to list all the files in the directory `/etc` and I cannot show the files that have 2 links.
I tried this command:

```
find /etc -links \2 -ls
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody have tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, one would generally use

```
find /etc \! -links 2 | xargs ls -d
```

The `!` is escaped because it can have meaning to various shells (you may not need that, adding it does no harm).  POSIX does not define a `-ls` option, though several Unix-*like* systems have implementations of this option. So I used [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html) (which is portable). I added a `-d` option, since I assumed you did not want to list the *contents* of the various directories which have subdirectories (and more than 2 links).

The `-not` predicate is not a POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) feature (and this was tagged "unix", not "linux").

For reference:

- [POSIX find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)
- [AIX find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm)
- [HP-UX find](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/find.1.html)
- [Solaris find](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/find-1.html#scrolltoc)
- [GNU find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)
- [FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find%281%29)
- [OSX find](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on which options are specified by POSIX and which are GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `-not` predicate to not list the files that have 2 links:

```
find /etc -not -links 2 -ls
```